# Jquery mobile multiple page problems

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, phonegap

i'm using jquery mobile for my development and for a new project i've decided to use multiple files.

```
index.html
locations.html
rewards.html
```

I'm linking the pages successfully like this.

```
index -> locations -> rewards
```

I'm able to load data dynamically when my locations.html page loads but having problems loading dynamic content to my rewards.html page after clicking a link on the locations.html page.

The ajax calls are working fine and I can see the content load via the console, but the content does not load on the page.

I am using a jquery mobile listview successfully on my locations.html page and can't load a listview on the rewards.html page.

Hope this makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

The problem with multiple HTML-files in a cordova app is, that every new file has to be managed like your index.html.

That means, that you have to include the cordova.js, your jQuery mobile JS, your app.js, … in every file and of course, you have to wait again for the cordova- and jQuery-deviceready-event.

That is the reason, why single-page-app are much simpler to manage.

Comment: I'm actually not adding the full html markup but just the <div data-rol="page" >, etc.. It loads fine and i have since gotten the dynamic content to load as well. My new problem is with a web form on a page. I can no longer use $().submit() e.preventDefault(). But if I add the form into the main index.html file it works great. I wish I could simply use it in the external profile.html page instead, just to keep my code clean. Any ideas...